# How to monitor traffic on gRPC call over Http2 on dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, grpc, http2

I'm using gRPC on dot net core and I create a service and a client.

Now I want to monitor traffic over HTTP/2 protocol, like Fiddler.

Are there any tools that can help us?